# SVG in pylons or turbogears?

Tags: svg, pylons, turbogears2

Are there documented pylons or turbogears2 widgets for generating SVG markup as components and are there example applications that use them returning an SVG primary document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pySVG looks like it might offer something along the lines of what you need. http://codeboje.de/pysvg/